# How do I get values of attributes using XElement/LINQ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, xelement

I'm trying to get the values of every id attribute on every  node.

Getting all the attributes with `.Descendants("foo").Attributes("id")` is simple enough, but is there a way to get an IEnumerable (Of String) containing the values?

I'd really prefer to avoid a loop, e.g.

```
For Each id in myXElement.Descendants("foo").Attributes("id")
    myIEnumerable.Add(id.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is C# rather than VB, but you should be able to use the following:

```
  var idList = from d in myXElement.Descendants("foo")
               select d.Attribute("id").Value;
```

which will return a variable of type `IEnumerable(Of String)`.